# Trying to show custom error if Python2 is run on a .py file fails due to syntax error (.py file contains f-strings)

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, f-string

I've written a program which requires Python 3 (we will not be supporting Python 2) but I'd like to include an error message informing the user of this, should they accidentally run the .py file in Python2.

I tried to do this using a version check in the first few lines of the file:

```
import sys
if not sys.version_info[0] == 3:
    sys.exit('You need to run this with Python 3')

# Lots of other code here....

# And then...
foo = 2
bar = 3
print(f"Some message that uses f-strings like this: variables are {foo} {bar}")
```

However, when the .py file is actually run using Python 2, it returns a syntax error on the line using f-strings. This is not very easy to understand.

Is there a way I can force the program to fail on the version check and thus, return the more useful error message?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it is actually run with Python2? `f-strings` are introduced in Python `3.6` So you might be running an earlier Python3 version... try `if sys.version_info < (3, 6)` and see if that changes anything. Or better yet, add a `print(sys.version)` just for sanity

Comment: Yes, f-strings require Python 3.6 or newer. If a given .py file needs to work in Python 2, you can't use syntax that's not supported in Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think the file is intended to work with Python3 but OP wants a descriptive message in case it is ran with Python2 (before hitting the syntax error)

Comment: I realise that f-string is a 3.6+ feature, but I'm interested in a way that my script can "fail" in a custom way when run using an older version, e.g. by saying "Version 3.6+ required". At present, the error about f-strings is confusing to users and they might simply think there's a bug in the software if they accidentally using an older Python version.

Comment: @Tomerikoo: yes, but you can't do that. The whole file must be parsed and compiled first, because those checks can be executed. And that means the *whole file must be compatible with Python 2*.

Comment: And yes, thanks @Tomerikoo , that's correct. It should (and does) operate correctly in Py3.6+. I just want a "user friendly" error if the user accidentally uses, say, Python 2. Is this possible?

Comment: @SLater01: you can't prevent all possible errors. Document the error in your FAQ, if this is a frequent occurrence. Much better: prevent it from being installed into unsupported Python versions, by [packaging your project](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/) and including [the supported Python versions](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires) in the package metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can force the program to fail on the version check and thus, return the more useful error message?

No, because Python first has to be able to parse and compile your file. That means you can only use *supported syntax* in the file, Python 2 can't parse f-strings.

You'll have to split up your project into multiple modules, and in the *first module to be imported* (say, the top-level `__init__.py` file of a package), do your version check before you import other modules that rely on Python-3 specific syntax.

Or *don't include such checks at all*. Instead, set [`python_requires`](https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#python-requires) for your project metadata, so that it won't be installed in older Python versions in the first place.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. This makes sense. It's a pity the syntax error can't be made more useful as at present, users will be confused if they're not aware of when features were introduced. I guess I'll look into your other 2 suggestions. Thanks

Comment: @SLater01: You'd never be able to add new syntax to the language if all files would have to be runnable on all older versions of the language.